# Unable to fetch a connection in 10 seconds:Tomcat jdbc pool connections are not releasing

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, tomcat7

As doing some operations,The connections active connections are incresed and after process they are becaming idle connections.Not releasing forever for a new connection.While processing Getting the error

> Unable to fetch a connection in 10 seconds:

Tomcat jdbc pool connections are not releasing.Im using tomcat 7.0.52 thinking it whould be the issue in tomcat.

Comment: Please include your code in your question.

Comment: Are you closing the connection after you are done using them? Closing connections is what returns them to the connection pool for reuse.

Comment: Im closing the connections properly,Maximum number of times ,the connections behaviour is normal.But in few cases the connections are not decresing.More over the idle connections are not decresing .